# C# XNA Lidgren client receives messages incorrectly

Tags: client, message, lidgren

I'm trying to make a simple server and client with Lidgren. The server is a C# console application and the client is made using XNA. The problem is when the client receives a message from the server, when it reads 2 floats it reads them as 0 (I'm assuming) even though they aren't sent like that.

Server: http://pastebin.com/s2cmBUf3
Client: http://pastebin.com/nrU7KFs8

Comment: How do I fix it? The server sends 2 floats containing the position the client sent it before but when the client receives it it's always 0 and because of that the box in the client never moves (it's always drawn at 0,0 coordinates).

Comment: I don't understand what could be wrong here...

Comment: Alright, so I added a Thread.Sleep(10) to the server at the end of the while() loop and the box moves on the client's side, but with a huge delay. How do I fix that?